# PHP log in not working num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

I have a problem with my script: i believe mysql_num_rows won't find anything from my database even though i know there is something in there (two records actually).... Anyone help?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die(mysql_error());
$db =  mysql_select_db("usersData", $con) or die(mysql_error());

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username, $con) or die(mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM `usersInfo` WHERE `Username`='$username'";
$result = mysql_query($con, $query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result) or die(mysql_error());

if($num_rows == 0)
{
    //header('Location: login.php');    
    echo "meow";
}
?>
```

i hope this is a better piece of code now. However, when i run it it now gives me a white page?

Comment: $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username); Where is $username initially defined?

Comment: it's always your fault. don't blame PHP.

Comment: Obligatory "don't use mysql_ functions" comment :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: -1 Your code lacks error checking albeit you ask here for debugging help. Not helpful.

Comment: $result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: $username is at the top to define that i am getting the posted text box.
Thank you for your obvious and unhelpful comment Karoly lol...

Okay, what should i use instead of mysql_functions rjdown?

What can i do to make the above work, can someone explain please?

Comment: Try @Adelphia recommendation to see what the actual error is so we can identify the problem. `$result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @Pearson95: You can greatly benefit by turning error reporting to the highest level while writing your code: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456)

Comment: Okay, thanks you guys! Sorry for my incompetent mistakes. I have added or die(mysql_error()) at the end of all my relevant fields. Should this suffice for relevant error finding or is this a bad way of figuring it out?

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking really obvious questions - i am a baby really...

Comment: If you get a white page (or a different error), please refer to [the PHP Error Reference we have on site](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456).

Comment: I have changed everything and no errors except "Undefined index"... however, even though i have the same error on the registration page and that works completely fine to insert data into a database now i get the same error on my login script and get a white page... any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Check these two lines:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `usersInfo` WHERE `Username`='$Username'";
```

variable `$username` is different than `$Username`

Variables in `php` are **case sensitive** so it is like you are using two different variables here.

Fix your `query` so it uses the same lower case `$username` variable you are setting above:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `usersInfo` WHERE `Username`='$username'";
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited it but i still get a 0 result from it all. 

`
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
 $db =  mysql_select_db("usersInfo", $con);
 
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `usersInfo` WHERE `Username`='$username'";
 $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 
 if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
 {
  //header('Location: login.php'); 
  echo "meow";
 }else{
  echo "now use session";
 }
`

Comment: @Pearson95 don't do that. If you have changed your code, change your question. Don't post entire code blocks  in the comments where noone can read them..

Comment: Okay, i apologise. New to coding and all this stack overflow business.

Comment: This answer does not acknowledge the fact that Pearson95 should stop using the mysql_* extensions, as per @rjdown's comment.

Comment: i have realised this and changed my mysql_functions to mysql_functions as an error stated using mysqli or PDO. Is this now better as i do not use mysql functions?